# solana token never arrived

Tags: wallet, phantom, transfer

i did 4 transacation, 3 on ether and one on solana. all was sucess, but the token never arrived..i made a complain on twitter, someone from the team come to me yesterday and try solve my problem. but i think its a scam...
After our system check on the provided address, we noticed the issue initiated as you informed us . Moving forward with resolving this issue,our team has granted a recovery process for this.
Replying to
metamsk
You need to validate your wallet  In other to rectify this issue
Do you know how to go about that ?
12:11 PM

Comment: Do *not* continue to share anything with that support team. Very likely a scam. Can you elaborate on the transaction you did on Solana?